# Tensorflow1.10 with python3.6

Tags: tensorflow

I used Mac OSX10.13.6, and install python3.6.5. But I cannot install tensorflow 1.10 as the instructions show on the official web. Does anyone finish the installing?

Comment: I have solved this problem with Ananconda~~

Answer (score 0):

Try installing tensorflow using pip.
`pip3 install tensorflow==1.10`

Comment: why not use pip3? We usually use pip for python2.x